# How to extract file name and extension from a decoded Base64 string in php

Tags: php

I'm uploading files to my PHP webservice by encoding them to Base64 and sending them via Json.

I'm decoding the data on the server using this code: `$file_content = base64_decode($file,true);`

Now I want to extract file name and extension from the `$file_content` variable.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**: here is the code I used to decode the file:

```
include '../conn.php';
include '../functions.php';

$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decodedJson = json_decode($entityBody);
$user_email = $decodedJson->{'email'};
$user_token = $decodedJson->{'token'};

$file = $decodedJson->{'file'};  //This is the encoded content of the file from JSON
$file_content = base64_decode($file,true);

if(!checkStudentAuthorizationOrHigher($user_email,$user_token,$conn))
{
    die();
}

//now I want to get $file_content type (extension or MIME type) and
//file name from the $file_content
//I tried the below code but it only gets file path as input parameter and doesn't work this way

echo mime_content_type($file_content);
```

Only the file content is given to my PHP webservice through JSON (file name or extension is not sent to my service). If it helps, the client side of my application is both a C# Windows Forms app and an Android app.

I want to save the file on the server with the same file name as the client side. Also I have to check the file type to make sure it is allowed on the server. (the file can be .pdf , .jpg , .jpeg or .zip)

Now is there a way to extract file info from `$file_content` variable?

Comment: Did you put the Filename and Extension into the base64 encoded string in javascript?

Comment: You dont give very much information about whats actually going on in your script. How about sharing some code with us so we can see what you are actually doing

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether `$file` is the name of the file or its contents. You might want to clarify.

Comment: @DavidFaber Updated my question and clarified

Comment: @RiggsFolly no I didn't use javascript at all, please take a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I used thw Intervention/image library https://github.com/Intervention/image
to deal with base64 encoded images. THis library got many other features as well.

```
$imageManager = new Intervention\Image\ImageManager();
$imageObject = $imageManager->make($base64EncodedImageSource);

$imageInfo = getimagesize($base64EncodedImageSource);
$this->mimeType = $imageInfo[2];
$extension = image_type_to_extension($this->mimeType);
$width = $imageInfo[0];
$height = $imageInfo[1];
$tempFilePath = '/path/to/file';
$imageObject->save($tempFilePath, 100);
```

Alternatively, if you have mime type of the file, you can use function [image_type_to_extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-extension.php) to get file extension

Comment: I am not trying to be a pain here but: From what the OP has actually said, all he has is a buffer containing a file of indeterminate type that they passed from javascript to PHP as a base64 encoded string. They have decoded it back to _something_ but nowhere do they say it is an image and even if it is it will not contain a Filename and an extension unless that data was added somehow to the string in the javascript. _Or am I missing something_

Comment: @RiggsFolly I haven't tried encoding files using javascript, but tried encoding files using php, which always had the MIME type along with the content.

Comment: the decoded file can be image/pdf or a zip file. Your answer only applies to images.

Comment: @ImanIrt Still you can use function `image_type_to_extension` to get extension from mime type. You need to have some information about the file to get extension. Otherwise you need to implement a universal parser for all type of files